# Show content from different website based on select menu value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a long select menu list, and I want to show a different table from a different website based on which select menu item they choose. I have javascript that dynamically changes the text inside the div based on select value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $.each(new Array(+this.value), function(i) {
        $('<div />', {
            text : 'this is div '+(i+1)

        }).appendTo('#result');
    });
});
  });
```

And I have php that shows a table from different website using Simple HTML DOM

```
<?php
        include('simple_html_dom.php');

        // get DOM from URL or file
        $html = file_get_html('http://www.generalconvention.org/gc/deputations?diocese_id=32');
        // Find all tables 
        foreach($html->find('table') as $element) 
        echo $element;
?>
```

But I cannot figure out how to change the url based on the select menu value and how to display the table from the url based on the select value without creating a huge amount of divs.

Comment: Paste some part of the html too please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this where diocese_id is the value of the current selected option.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        $("#result").load("yourfile.php", {diocese_id:$(this).val()});
    });
});
```

On the php side:

```
<?php
        include('simple_html_dom.php');

        // get DOM from URL or file
        $url = "http://www.generalconvention.org/gc/deputations?diocese_id=" . $_REQUEST['diocese_id'];
        $html = file_get_html($url);
        // Find all tables 
        foreach($html->find('table') as $element) 
        echo $element;
?>
```

Comment: This works great, but how do I change the url in the PHP file to the selectmenu value?